# Why wolfram alpha is not showing integrand error?

Tags: inverse-function, multiple-integral, wolfram-alpha, calculator

$\tanh^{-1}$ of any real number whose modulus is $1$ or greater than $1$ is meaningless. So the following double integral must be meaningless. But when I computed the following double integral in Wolfram alpha, it did not show any integrand error:

[image]

Obviously $\sqrt{300-20y+y^2-20z+z^2}$ is greater than $y-10$ for any real $y$ and $z$. So what is wrong here?

> **EDIT:** Have a look at [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=Integrate%5BzArcTanh%5BDivide%5BSqrt%5BPower%5By%2C2%5D%2BPower%5Bz%2C2%5D-20y%2B20z%2B1100%5D%2Cy-10%5D%5D%2C%7By%2C-20%2C20%7D%2C%7Bz%2C-20%2C20%7D%5D). Wolfram is neither showing error or complex values. What does it mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may explain what Wolfram Alpha is doing:

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=tanh%5E-1%282%29

This shows that Wolfram Alpha will treat $\tanh^{-1}$ as a complex-valued function when you give it input that is outside the domain of the real-valued $\tanh^{-1}$ function.

In your example, Wolfram Alpha appears to be integrating $\tanh^{-1}$ as a function with complex values
since you gave it an integral that cannot be integrated assuming $\tanh^{-1}$ is a real-valued function.

Note that in this case it gave you a complex result at the end, not a real number: it includes the term $4.54747\times 10^{-13}i.$
Due to the very small size of this term, I suspect that it is actually due to numerical error in the calculation and that a more exact calculation would have completely canceled out any imaginary components.
In the second example the cancellation may work out exactly, as numerical calculations sometimes do. As suggested in a comment, you may be able to see a meaningful imaginary component (not just numerical error) if you try different bounds of integration.

Comment: But have a look at [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=Integrate%5BzArcTanh%5BDivide%5BSqrt%5BPower%5By%2C2%5D%2BPower%5Bz%2C2%5D-20y%2B20z%2B1100%5D%2Cy-10%5D%5D%2C%7By%2C-20%2C20%7D%2C%7Bz%2C-20%2C20%7D%5D). It is neither showing error nor giving any complex values. Please let me put it in the question.

Comment: @lorilori: Could be that the imaginary part cancels (except for a small numerical error) because of symmetry? What do you get if you change the bounds of integration a little, to break the symmetry?

Comment: I see. Thanks...